# not support css properties in itext7.pdfhtml at all

Tags: itext, itext7, html-to-pdf

I'm using `itext7.pdfHtml` adds-on to convert my html template to PDF doc and everything is ok and result produce without any error but my is that there were a bunch of CSS properties that not recognizable with pdfhtml dll.
some of these  properties are show at this snippet:

```
.day-meta-wrapper {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: normal;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #00000033;----> not support
    padding: 0 6px;
    display: flex;----> not support
    align-items: center;----> not support
    justify-content: center;----> not support
}
```

this my html file result:

[image]

as you can see in browser view there's no problem and all of the properties work properly
but this is my PDF result:
[image]

as shown in the picture PDF doc loosed CSS properties

```css
h1 {
    background-color: red;
}

.day-meta {
    margin: 5px 0;
    user-select: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.day-meta-wrapper {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: normal;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #00000033;
    padding: 0 6px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/DayMeta.css">
</head>
<body style="background: #979797;">
    <h1>Hello IText7 PDFHtml</h1>
    <div class="day-meta">
        <div class="day-meta-wrapper">
            <div>December 11, 2018</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, could you clarify what is the question that you have? You are right that `display: flex` is not supported.

Comment: @AlexeySubach  Hi, i noted in the question that there were many CSS properties like `display:flex` that not add to my PDF result

Comment: @AlexeySubach I added two pictures of my files that i think helpful to understanding my question

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get your question.The problem you face is described quite clearly but I don't see a question in your post.